# Update one list with values from another list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples containing user data as given below (2nd value of tuple is age)

```
l1 = [('uid1','23','F'),('uid2','35','M'),('uid3','25','M'),.....]
```

I need to update the age values from another list as given below:

```
l2 = [('uid1','24'),('uid2','37'),....]
```

Tuples in l2 have only two elements, size of l2 is smaller than l1 but not all values of l2 may be present in l1, so only those values which are present in l1 will have to be updated. How to create a new list l3 as below?

```
l3 = [('uid1','24','F'),('uid2','37','M'),('uid3','25','M'),.....]
```

Please suggest how to go about this.

#Update 1
I tried converted l2 into a dictionary:

```
d = {x[0]:x[1] for x in l2}
```

and then,

```
l3 = [(x[0],d[x[0]],x[2]) for x in l1]
```

but it throws error where corresponding `d[x[0]]` is not found in `d`. How to avoid this and retain the older value?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using dicts instead of tuples...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I tried that and I have updated the original post

Comment: Can you give a clear input/output example? Do you need `l3` to have all values with `l1` with the ones also in `l2` updated, or the values of `l2` with the ones also in `l1` updated?

Comment: @Tomerikoo l3 should contain all tuples as l1 with age values updated from l2 wherever possible. If l2 doesnt have a tuple (userid) which is present in l1 then it will not be updated in l3 and will be retained as is.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an `O(n^2)` run-time (for each tuple in `l1`, check if it is in `l2`), it is better to use a dictionary to map name to age:

```py
l2_d = dict(l2)
```

And now it is easier to check if a certain name has a replacement age. We iterate `l1` and take the matching age from `l2` or the original if it doesn't exists in `l2`. Then simply add the tuples to the new list with the appropriate age:

```py
l3 = []

for name, age, gender in l1:
    age = l2_d.get(name, age)
    l3.append((name, age, gender))
```

This can then also be reduced to a list-comprehension but it might be on the edge of readability border:

```py
l3 = [(name, l2_d.get(name, age), gender) for name, age, gender in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
d2={i[0]:i[1] for i in l2}

l3=[]

for i in l1:
    if i[0] in d2:
        l3.append((i[0], d2[i[0]], i[2]))
    else:
        l3.append(i)
```

For

```
l1=[('uid1', '23', 'F'), ('uid2', '35', 'M'), ('uid3', '25', 'M')]
l2=[('uid1', '24'), ('uid2', '37')]
```

Output will be:

```
>>> print(l3)
[('uid1', '24', 'F'), ('uid2', '37', 'M'), ('uid3', '25', 'M')]
```